VBA with ADO, multiple data source connections
I am trying to join tables that have different data sources; ThisWorkbook on SQL Server.
Below is my attempt.
When trying to run this, a runtime error is displayed.  I am not surprised by the error.  I didn’t really expect it to run and can’t think of how else to try.
Both connections are successful when running in separate subroutines.
Appreciate any help!
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection
Dim cnPubsSQL As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubsSQL = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String, strConnSQL As String, fldCount As Long, iCol As Long, Slct As String, SQLfrom As String, 

BouncePNs = "`" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "$`"""

strConn = strConn & "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
strConn = strConn & " Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml"""
cnPubs.Open strConn
strConnSQL = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConnSQL = strConnSQL & "DRIVER={SQLServer};SERVER=XXSQLP02\XXSQLP02;UID=product_user;PWD=xxxx;Database=product"
cnPubsSQL.Open strConnSQL

Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

Slct = "SELECT Whse, Mfg,[Part Number] "

SQLfrom = "  FROM "
SQLfrom = SQLfrom & BouncePNs
SQLfrom = SQLfrom & "LEFT OUTER JOIN vwPart"
SQLfrom = SQLfrom & "ON " & BouncePNs & ".PN = vwPart.[Part Number]"

Workbooks.Add
With rsPubs
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubsSQL
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    .Open Slct & SQLfrom
    fldCount = rsPubs.Fields.Count
    For iCol = 1 To fldCount
        Cells(1, iCol).Value = rsPubs.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
    Next iCol
    Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsPubs
    .Close
End With


What is the runtime error code and description?

You can't combine multiple connections into one query. The SQL statement is executed at the database (even if that database is Excel), not on the client side (your code), and every database knows only itself, not any other database. ADO is just a wrapper to send commands to a database and receive the results.
Your recordset (rsPubs) has exactly one connection, (currently cnPubs) and the SQL statement will be executed using that connection. I assume that your SQL tries to join data from your sheet with data from your database, and that simply cannot work.
Possible workarounds:

Loop over your Excel data and issue a separate SQL statement for every row of your data (you should dig into ADODB.Parameter to speed up the process).

Write the content of the Excel into a temp table on your database and execute the join on DB side.

Load the relevant data from your database into a separate sheet (maybe use an In-clause) and execute the join on Excel side.



Thanks for the explanation and the suggestions.  I thought that it probably was not possible to combine multiple connections into one query.
The best option would be to load a temp table in SQL server, but I don’t have security for that.
Looping through the excel rows is the method I normally use and have been hoping to find a better solution.  I will try to dig into ADODB.Parameter.
